# Java - Enums Switch with Instantiated Variable

Tags: enums, switch-statement, instantiation

Given the code below:

```
    public class Practice1 {

       public enum Dogs {collie, harrier};

         public static void main(String[] args) {
             Dogs myDog = Dogs.collie;

          switch (myDog) {
          case collie:
              System.out.println("collie ");
          case harrier:
              System.out.println("harrier ");
           }
       }
}
```

The output is

```
    collie
    harrier
```

Why does it print out both cases when *Dogs myDog = Dogs.collie*?
I realize that there are no breaks but shouldn't it still only print *collie*?

Furthermore, with *Dogs myDog = Dogs.harrier* it only print *harrier*

Comment: That's how the switch statement works. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

If there are no breaks, all remaining cases are executed, which is why *Dogs myDog = Dogs.harrier* will only print *harrier*.